# The difference between services and Service Applications

Tags: service-application, searchserviceapplication

What is the difference between a **service** (for example the search service - something like SharepointSearch 15) and a **Service Application** (for example the Search Service Application in Central Administration)?

Thank you!

This question is NOT a duplicate as it asks about the difference between a service and a SERVICE application, NOT between a service and a WEB Application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a service and an application in Sharepoint 2013?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/112313/what-is-the-difference-between-a-service-and-an-application-in-sharepoint-2013)

Comment: @AtishDipongkor nope, it's not a duplicate, this question refers to a SERVICE Application, not to a Web Application like in the one you linked

Comment: I can see your answer is there. Please read the other answers with comments. **SharePoint facilitates several services such like user profile, secure token, business connectivity and etc.. which are supported at farm level. An application is a web application where it also lies in the same level as services**

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question, you can find the better explanation in [technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee704554.aspx)

"*In SharePoint 2013, individual services can be configured independently and third-party companies can add services. The services infrastructure gives you control over which services are deployed and how services are shared.

Services that are deployed are named service applications. A service application provides a resource that can be shared across sites throughout a farm, and can be accessed by users through a hosting web application. Service applications are associated to web applications by service application connections. Some services can be shared across farms.* "